# Laravel Date Difference with Carbon

Tags: laravel, php-carbon, laravel-mail

I am trying to `send email three days before the expired date,` but I'm not sure how to?

**Logic**

1. Retrieve all subscribers that are three days left to expire
2. Send email to their users

**Code**

Table I need to check timestamps  named `subscribes.`

```php
$subscribes = Subscribe::all();
```

This table has a column named `expires_at` which I need to check this for finding `3 days left.`

And my mailing

```php
Mail::to($user->email)->send(new SubscribeExpire($user, $subscribe));
```

I'm confused with this Carbon calculation thing, anyone can help with that?

## Update

based on answer below now I have this:

```
$subscribes = Subscribe::where('expires_at', Carbon::now()->subDays(3))->get();
        $user = [];
        $package = [];
        foreach($subscribes as $subscribe){
            $user = User::where('email', $subscribe->email);
            $package = Package::where('id', $subscribe->package_id);
        }

        Mail::to($user->email)->send(new SubscribeExpire($user, $package));
```

but when I run the command it get this error

```
ErrorException  : Trying to get property 'email' of non-object
```

Comment: $user = User::where('email', $subscribe->email) should be $user = User::where('email', $subscribe->email)->first();

Comment: The same goes to Package.

Comment: then what if i have several subscribes for different users? it only gets first one right?

Comment: In such case use "->get()"  instead of "->first()" and use foreach loop to iterate through these users and send an email to each of these users.

Comment: @NickSurmanidze I used get, also moved my Mail inside loop but not sending email, the `dd` of `user` returns `[]` only

Comment: I just added it as an answer. It was just easier to put a code snippet there. Take a look if that will work for you.

Comment: @mafortis, you really should have already established a relationship between the Subcribe model and the User model.   While you may have gotten something that works now, it's not a clean approach and will be frowned upon by other Laravel developers.  I highly recommend you read through the entirety of the Laravel docs so you understand the ORM and the Laravel workflow.

Comment: @Devon thanks for suggestion, i have relation between them i just saved email here instead of user_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  // here you get subscribes  
  // if you are going to send three days before the expiry date, this means we need to check if expires_at is in three days so probably need to add days. Or maybe even check if time left before expiration is more than three days and less than one day and run it once per day?
  $subscribes = Subscribe::whereDate('expires_at', Carbon::now()->addDays(3))->get();
    $user = [];
    $package = [];
    foreach($subscribes as $subscribe){
        // you probably have only one user with this email
        $user = User::where('email', $subscribe->email)->first();
        // you probably have one associated package
        $package = Package::where('id', $subscribe->package_id)->first();
    }
    // check if user and package are found
    if(is_object($user) && is_object($package)){
      Mail::to($user->email)->send(new SubscribeExpire($user, $package));
    }
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work, my best guess is it has problem finding the user because it always return `[]`

Comment: I've updated the answer. My guess is that it is returning you your empty array you assigned to user. The issue might be in the first line.

Comment: life saver :D. Thank you so much it finally does send email

Comment: You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [subDays()](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) method as shown below:

```
$subscribes = Subscribe::where('expires_at', Carbon::now()->subDays(3))->get();
```

Comment: `Q1` do I need to loop this in order to get users for their emails? `Q2` if i loop it the will it send email to all those users of just first one it finds? how should i define array of results in my `Mail::...`?

Comment: updated my question.

Comment: If expires_at is a timestamp, this won't work so well as you're looking at an exact comparison.

Comment: yes is timestamp, what yu suggest now?

Comment: @mafortis, you really shouldn't add additional questions once you have an answer.   Read the "How to Ask" section under Help.  Don't ask multiple questions in one, SO is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum where the answers can be broad and discussed.

Comment: @Devon is not multiple is same question not solved yet. if you see my logic part i mentioned i need to get users to send email to.

Comment: Move Mail::to($user->email)->send(new SubscribeExpire($user, $package)); into foreach loop

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain that doesn't return error neither sending email, i tried to dump `user` it just return `[]`